# Loading georeferenced map TIFF image into shapefile using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, vectorization

I need to add this Lake County townships map into a shapefile that contains other counties' townships. The shapefile's fields are: Township, Shape, Shape_Length, Shape_Area and County.

How can I do this in ArcMap 10.4?

[image]

Comment: are you sure this data doesn't exist in vector shapefile already?

Comment: I found the map image on Lake County's website. https://portico.mygisonline.com/html5/?viewer=lakeinsurveyor
The only formats available are png, bmp, jpeg, tiff, geotiff, pdf. I have searched all over the internet and can confirm there is no shp data for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPSSpatial's comment that this data might already exist in vector form is worth investigating as that's the easiest option. I would start by looking at the [US Census](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography.html).

If not, you'll have to digitize (trace) the features you want from your TIFF to create a vector shapefile with the same fields before combining it with your other data.

Comment: After extensive searching on US Census, including when I started the project yesterday, I haven't been able to find such data. They have demographic data for individual townships, but nothing like county maps with townships. 
I have created a feature class from 11 polygons, so I'll just add and populate the fields and load it into the main townships shp. Your comment is the answer, thank you.